# Ternary operator with no condition

Tags: c++

I found a section of code that shows the following:

```
int A = 4;
int Z;

Z = (A ? 55 : 3);
```

Why does the result for Z give 55?

Comment: `A` gets implicitly converted to `bool` and any numeric value different than `0` is evaluated as `true`.

Comment: Possible doplicate: [bool to int conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369770/bool-to-int-conversion)

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have a common misconception about the fact that expressions in conditional statements (`if`, `while`, ...) and ternary operations must "look like" a condition, so they should contain a relational/equality/logical operator.

It's not like that. Commonly used relational/equality/... operators don't have any particular relationship with conditional statements/expressions; they can live on their own

```
bool foo = 5 > 4;
std::cout<<foo<<"\n"; // prints 1
```

and conditional statements/expressions don't care particularly for them

```
if(5) std::cout << "hello\n"; // prints hello
```

`if`/`?`/`while`/... just evaluate the expression, check if the result, converted to `bool`, is `true` or `false`, and act accordingly. If the expression doesn't "looks like" a condition is irrelevant, as long as the result can be converted to `bool` you can use it in a conditional.

Now, in this particular case `A` evaluates to 4, which is not zero, so when converted to `bool` is `true`, hence the ternary expression evaluates to its second expression, so `55`.