# Bitwise AND: why do I get this behaviour?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have this simple program here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main() {

unsigned char a = 0b11100111; 
if((a & (1<<2)) == true) // THIS IS THE LINE
    cout << "Entering if block!" << endl;
else
    cout << "Too bad, maybe next time.." << endl;
bitset<8> x(a & (1<<2));
cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Can you tell me why this `if((a & (1<<2)) == true)` outputs:
**Too bad, maybe next time..
00000100**

While this `if((a & (1<<2))` outputs:
**Entering if block!
00000100**

I'm compiling with g++ -std=c++14.

Comment: Because `0b100 != true`
Try `!= 0` in your if.

Comment: When `true` is promoted to an integral type, its value is `1`: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369783/10871073

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0b100` is a number and shouldn't be compared against true.

Try changing your if statement to:

```
if (a & (1<<2))
```

or equivalently

```
if((a & (1<<2)) != 0)
```

since in an `if` statement, anything not zero is considered `true`.

Comment: Just one more reason to not use `== true` in conditions.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that this happens because `true == 1` in a numerical context.

Comment: Thanks! So basically for what concerns binary numbers (in 8bit for instance), everything that isn't 0000 0000 is considered equal to 1?

Comment: @Barnercart anything that is *not* `0` (zero) is considered `true`. `0` is considered `false`.

Comment: @Barnercart, In an `if` statement, anything not zero is considered true. In your case, it may be clearer to put `if((a & (1<<2)) != 0)` as your if statement.

Comment: @LarryB: Hope you don't mind my edit (and have an upvote) - your last comment really nails it; worth promoting to the answer.

Comment: I see now. `if((a & (1<<2)) != 0)` indeed works like a charm. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

This epitomises the pitfalls in using superfluous `== true` which some folk like to use in the purported interests of clarity: sometimes it breaks code.

When `(a & (1<<2)) == true` is evaluated, `true` (a `bool` type) is implicitly converted to an `int` type with value `1`, and for that matter `a` is converted to an `int` type too.

But `(a & (1<<2))` is not `1`, so the `else` is ran.

Did you want the far more normal `if (a & (1<<2))`?