# C: Make sure TRUE is equal to exactly 1

Tags: c, boolean

I would like to sum over a number of `bool` variables to find out how many of them are `TRUE`. Since there is no real `bool` type in C (only `int`), I cannot be entirely sure that `TRUE` means exactly `1`. It could theoretically be any integer greater than zero.
What is a computationally efficient and readable way to ensure this?

P.S. I am aware of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369770/bool-to-int-conversion). However, my case is slightly different, as the `bool` values don't come from an internal truth check, but from an external source (CAN signal).

Comment: `if (TRUE == 1) ....` But this is quite useless exercise as the standard guarantees that `true` defined in `stdbool.h` expands to `1`

Comment: C does have a Boolean type, since C 1999. It is called `_Bool`, and `<stdbool.h>` adds `bool` as an alias.

Comment: I suspect your actual question is you want to count the number of non-zero values in a number of items. Ideally their values would be 0 or 1, but you do not trust where they came from and now want to count the number of non-zero values rather than simply adding them all. Suppose they have integer type, you can do this with `sum += (_Bool) x;`, `sum += !!x;`, or `if (x) ++sum;`.

Comment: If, if true is “any integer greater than zero”, and you have to deal with negative values that mean false, then you can use `sum += 0 < x;` or `if (0 < x) ++sum;`. You should edit to clarify the problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for re-formulating my question more precisely. This is exactly what I wanted. I like `sum += !!x;` best, as it is works without external libraries and avoids an additional `if` check.

Answer (score 2):

Never use a `_Bool` (or `bool` defined by `#include <stdbool.h>`) if it is possible for the object to contain a value other than 0 or 1. The compiler is at liberty to assume the object will contain a value of 0 or 1 and produce unexpected results if it contains a different value.  In particular, GCC tends to produce unexpected results from the following program:

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    _Bool b;
    memset(&b, 0xff, sizeof b);
    printf("int = %d\n", (int)b);
    printf("int_bool = %d\n", (int)(_Bool)b);
    printf("int_bool_int = %d\n", (int)(_Bool)(int)b);
    printf("int_not_not = %d\n", (int)!!b);
    printf("not_not_int = %d\n", !!(int)b);
    return 0;
}
```

On Debian GNU/Linux 11 x86_64:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gcc -O2 foo.c -o foo
$ ./foo
int = 255
int_bool = 255
int_bool_int = 255
int_not_not = 255
not_not_int = 255
```

One might have expected most of those printed values to be 1 rather than 255.

Comment: This is a weird one.  It happens even with -O0, and according to godbolt it was gcc 9.4 that first exhibited this.