# C++ what does this piece of code do?

Tags: c++

In my book there a piece of code I don't understand. It's sadly not explained what it does...

```
int big = 200;
int small = 100;
int max = (a <= b) ? big : small;
```

So what I know is that there are 3 variables (lol..).
The integer 'max' gets the value of big, but why ? `(a <= b)` is obviously a condition, but what do the '?' and ':' do?

I hope someone could explain me...

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1AUq5Di1/

Comment: omfg why am I getting these down votes? It wasnt explained in my book and when I googled it nothing useful came out!

Comment: Did you try searching for `[c++] "?"` here on Stack Overflow?

Comment: ops no not here on stack overflow... damn >.<

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does '?' do in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795286/what-does-do-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?` is a [ternary operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a)

```
int max = (a <= b) ? big : small;
```

is same with

```
int max;
if(a <= b) max = big;
else max = small;
```

Answer (score 4):

If `a` is less or equal to `b` then max is equal to big, else max is equal to small. For more check [Ternary Operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1AUq5Di1/)

Answer (score 4):

`?:` is conditional operator.

```
int max =(a<=b) ? big : small
```

means if `a<=b` is true then `max=big i.e. 200`  else `max=small i.e. 100`

General syntax:

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

Comment: (Pedantic) More correctly, `?` and `:` together are the conditional assignment operator. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Conditional_assignment

Answer (score 3):

This is the same as:

```
if(a <= b){
    max = big;
}
else{
    max = small;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the same:

```
int big = 200, small = 100, max;

if (a <= b)
  max= big;
else
  max = small;
```