# Cryptic for-loop statement

Tags: c++

I am looking at some open source software and they use a for loop/operators in a different way then I have seen and I was wondering if someone can tell me what it is doing in English.
I believe the open source is in C, maybe C++, not sure if it makes a difference but I am working in C++.

The for loop given is, TSTEP=60, tt and t are just double variables

```
for (tt=t<0.0?-TSTEP:TSTEP;fabs(t)>1E-9;t-=tt)
```

Comment: I’m not sure what caused the downvotes. The title isn’t very descriptive though.

Comment: I think the part you wouldnt understand is this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    if(t < 0)
        tt = -TSTEP;
    else
        tt = TSTEP;

    for(; fabs(t) > 1E-9; t -= tt)
```

Hopefully this is deciphered enough

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly ugly code, but really the only confusing part is the first part of the `for` statement:

```
tt=t<0.0?-TSTEP:TSTEP;
```

It might be easier to read with brackets:

```
tt = (t < 0.0 ? -TSTEP : TSTEP);
```

In English, this is "if `t` is less than `0.0`, assign `-TSTEP` to `tt`, otherwise assign `TSTEP` to `tt`". If you haven't seen this syntax before, look up the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795286/what-does-do-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

I guess the `?:` operator is what puzzles you. The loop itself changes t by tt (60) steps in the direction towards 0, until t is almost 0, independent of if `t` was positive or negative from the start.
`lvalue = (expr ? a : b)` is a common shorthand for

```
if (expr) {
  lvalue = a;
} else {
  lvalue = b;
}
```