# "DHT11 ? 0 : -40;" What does this syntax mean and what is it called?

Tags: c++, arduino

`return model == DHT11 ? 0 : -40;`

I believe it means "return model if between 0 and -40", but I'd like a definitive answer.

Comment: Don't believe your intuition.

Comment: search up ternary operations

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392932/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does '?' do in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795286/what-does-do-in-c)

Answer (score 6):

Its the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C), equivalent to:

```
if (model == DHT11)
    return 0;
else
    return -40;
```

so it has nothing to do with a check for a range.

The ternary operator yields a value, i.e. you could also use this in an assignment like:

```
retval = model == DHT11 ? 0 : 40;
return retval;
```

Answer (score 0):

This operator (E1?E2:E3) is called ternary operator, where E are expressions.

It means  : "If E1 is true, return E2, else, return E3"

Here's a [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) to cppreference explaning a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, it is called the ternary operator.

The ternary operator checks to see if something is true, and if it is, yields the value before the `:`. If it is false, it yields the value after the `:`.

In this situation, it checks to see if `model == DHT11` evaluates to true, and gives 0 if so. If `model == DHT11` evaluates to false, it gives -40. The value the ternary evaluates to is then given to `return`, quitting the function, and returning either 0 or -40.

Other example:

```
std::string hi = "hi";
std::cout << (hi == "hi") ? "string hi contains \"hi\"." : "string hi does not contain \"hi\"." << "\n";
```

Would print:

`string hi contains "hi".`

General Syntax:

`bool ? value1 : value2`

The ternary operator is just like an if-else statement, compacted down to one line.