# what's this function mean ( sry for my english )

Tags: c++

what's this mean

int find(int u) { return P[u] = P[u] == u ? u : find(P[u]); }

full code(c++)
-it tell which number are connected.

```
   #include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int N = 1e5+5;

int n, m, k;
int P[N];

int find(int u) { return P[u] = P[u] == u ? u : find(P[u]); }

int main() {
    scanf("%d %d %d", &n, &m, &k);
    iota(P, P+N, 0);
    for(int i = 0, a, b; i < m; ++i) {
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        a = find(a), b = find(b);
        P[a] = b;
    }
    for(int i = 0, a, b; i < k; ++i) {
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        puts(find(a) == find(b) ? "yes" : "no");
    }
}
```

input-
3 2 3
1 2
2 1
2 3
3 1
1 2

out put-
no
no
yes

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Comment: Ask the person who wrote it to explain it, document it, and use meaningful variable names. We can only guess at what they intended; and, for what it's worth, I've tried and failed.

Comment: Handy reading: [What does '?' do in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795286/what-does-do-in-c)

Comment: This should be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2079303

Comment: That code was not written to be read. It wouldn't survive code review at most companies, so don't expect to learn much from it.

Answer (score 0):

`int find(int u) { return P[u] = P[u] == u ? u : find(P[u]); }`

equal

```
int find(int u ) {
  if ( p[u] == u ) p[u] = u;
    else P[u] = find(P[u]);
  return P[u];
}
```

This is another way of writing

```
condition ? consequent : alternative
```

Comment: Right, but what does it _mean_?

Comment: What Atsteroids is trying to get you do do is explain the program behaviour the code is trying to express. What is that code doing? How does it solve the problem it's supposed to solve? What is the problem the code is supposed to solve?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Oh, I misunderstood what he meant

Comment: @user4581301 Oh, I misunderstood what he meant. English is not my native language.

Comment: @Itati it's possible that all the questioner cares about is the syntax, but in general a discussion of syntax is of little use without discussing the behaviour the syntax is supposed to express.