# C++: What does ": cout" or "? cout" mean?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

so i have this linear search code, mostly i know everything that happens in that code. But now I struggle at the end... I tried to google it but somehow did not find anything....

Here is the Code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int search(int k, int array[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (array[i] == k)
            return i;
    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = { 2, 3, 4, 10, 40 };
    int k = 10;
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    cout << size << endl;

    int result = search(k, array, size);
    (result == -1)
        ? cout << "K gibt es nicht"
        : cout << "K Gefunden: " << result;
    return 0;
}
```

So my question.. What does the `:` and the `?` before the `cout` mean?

```
? cout << "K gibt es nicht"
: cout << "K Gefunden: " << result;
```

Comment: Look at [ternary operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator).

Comment: I would use a simple `if` here BTW: `if (result == -1) { std::cout << "K gibt es nicht"; } else { std::cout << "K Gefunden: " << result; }`

Comment: dupe of [What does '?' do in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795286/what-does-do-in-c) or many others, e.g. search for _stackoverflow c++ question mark colon_

Comment: On a side note, that's abusing the poor conditional expression.

Answer (score -4):

It's the ternary operator, which is short hand notation for an if, else statement.

Before the `?` is the operated which is evaluated as a true/false value.

`?` the code after is executed if the operand evaluates to true.
`:` the code after is executed if the operand evaluates to false.

So

```
 (result == -1)
        ? cout << "K gibt es nicht"
        : cout << "K Gefunden: " << result;
```

is short hand for:

```
if(result == -1) {
 cout << "K gibt es nicht";
} else {
  cout << "K Gefunden: " << result;
}
```

Comment: ternary operator yields in *expression*. *if-statement* is.. a *statement*.

Comment: In general, this answer is too shallow, to the point of glaring over quite important details. Ternary operator in general is not a short hand notation, it has distinct properties. There is already a duplicate to the question.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah yes, how many C++ programmers does it take to program a lightbulb...